# Making a moving "camera" for a HTML game

Tags: javascript

I am building a side scroller game using HTML and javascript. I need help understanding how to build a movable focal point that fixes itself on the main moving sprite as it goes through the world. My canvas is 2000 x 2000 and I would want to build a camera that is about 750 x 750.

[My Game](https://jsfiddle.net/mittank1701/xs3ah430/4/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var positionX = 100.0;
var positionY = 175.0;
var velocityX = 4.0;
var velocityY = 0.0;
var gravity = 0.5;
var onGround = false;
var deaths = 0;
var points = 0;
var color = "#000000";

//cirlce 1
var point1x1 = 339;
var point1x2 = 372;
var point1y1 = 110;
var point1y2 = 150;
var circlex1 = 350;
var circley1 = 100;

//circle 2
var point2x1 = 565;
var point2x2 = 590;
var point2y1 = 90;
var point2y2 = 150;
var circlex2 = 575;
var circley2 = 100;

//cirlce 3
var point3x1 = 855;
var point3x2 = 880;
var point3y1 = 20;
var point3y2 = 50;
var circlex3 = 865;
var circley3 = 35;


window.addEventListener("mousedown", StartJump, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", EndJump, false);

Loop();

function StartJump()
{
    if(onGround)
    {
        velocityY = -12.0;
        onGround = false;
    }
}

function EndJump()
{
    if(velocityY < -6.0)
        velocityY = -6.0;
}

function Loop()
{
    Update();
    Render();
    window.setTimeout(Loop, 30);    
}

function Update()
{
    velocityY += gravity;
    positionY += velocityY;
    positionX += velocityX;

    // Collision Detection //
    if ((positionX > 239 && positionX < 292 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 439 && positionX < 492 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 639 && positionX < 692 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 145) || (positionX > 839 && positionX < 892 && positionY > 50 && positionY < 100))
    {
    positionY = 175;
      positionX = 50;
    deaths++;
    points = 0;

// circle 1

    circlex1 = 350;
    circley1 = 100;
    point1x1 = 339;
    point1x2 = 372;
    point1y1 = 110;
    point1y2 = 150;

//circle 2

        circlex2 = 575;
        circley2 = 100;
        point2x1 = 565;
        point2x2 = 595;
        point2y1 = 90;
        point2y2 = 150;

//circle 3

        point3x1 = 855;
    point3x2 = 880;
    point3y1 = 20;
    point3y2 = 50;
    circlex3 = 865;
    circley3 = 35;

    }

    if(positionY > 175.0)
    {
        positionY = 175.0;
        velocityY = 0.0;
        onGround = true;
    }

// End World
    if(positionX < 10 || positionX > 2000)
    velocityX *= -1;      

// Point 1
   if(positionX > point1x1 && positionX < point1x2 && positionY > point1y1 && positionY < point1y2)
    {
    points++;
    circlex1 = -10;
    circley1 = -10;
    point1x1 = -10;
    point1x2 = -10;
    point1y1 = -10;
    point1y2 = -10;

    }


// Point 2
if(positionX > point2x1 && positionX < point2x2 && positionY > point2y1 && positionY < point2y2)
    {
    points++;
    circlex2 = -10;
    circley2 = -10;
    point2x1 = -10;
    point2x2 = -10;
    point2y1 = -10;
    point2y2 = -10;
    }

// Point 3
if(positionX > point3x1 && positionX < point3x2 && positionY > point3y1 && positionY < point3y2)
    {
    points++;
    circlex3 = -10;
    circley3 = -10;
    point3x1 = -10;
    point3x2 = -10;
    point3y1 = -10;
    point3y2 = -10;
    }

}


function drawSquare1() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(250, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCircle1() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex1, circley1, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCircle2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex2, circley2, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCircle3() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex3, circley3, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}


function drawSquare2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(450, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare3() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(650, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare5() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare4() {
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850, 50, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawDeaths() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Deaths: "+deaths, 8, 20);
}

function drawPoints() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Points: "+points, 8, 50);
}

function Render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    drawCircle1();
    drawCircle2();
    drawCircle3();
    drawSquare1(); 
    drawSquare2();
    drawSquare3();
    drawSquare4();
    drawSquare5();
    drawDeaths();
    drawPoints();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,175);
    ctx.lineTo(2000,175);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(positionX - 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX - 10, positionY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Took me 15 tires to get that third pellet! you may consider grouping all the non moving objects in to one function so that the can all be moved at the same time to simulate a moving frame. good luck. great start. the physics of the jumping is very smooth.

Comment: @T3.0 Thanks! I needed help understanding how the logic would work and what you said clarified the code given to me by the person below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code. I hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var positionX = 100.0;
  var positionY = 175.0;
  var velocityX = 2.3;
  var velocityY = 0.0;
  var gravity = 0.5;
  var onGround = false;
  var deaths = 0;
  var points = 0;
  var color = "#000000";

  //cirlce 1
  var point1x1 = 339;
  var point1x2 = 372;
  var point1y1 = 110;
  var point1y2 = 150;
  var circlex1 = 350;
  var circley1 = 100;

  //circle 2
  var point2x1 = 565;
  var point2x2 = 590;
  var point2y1 = 90;
  var point2y2 = 150;
  var circlex2 = 575;
  var circley2 = 100;

  //cirlce 3
  var point3x1 = 855;
  var point3x2 = 880;
  var point3y1 = 20;
  var point3y2 = 50;
  var circlex3 = 865;
  var circley3 = 35;


  window.addEventListener("mousedown", StartJump, false);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", EndJump, false);

  Loop();

  function StartJump() {
    if (onGround) {
      velocityY = -12.0;
      onGround = false;
    }
  }

  function EndJump() {
    if (velocityY < -6.0)
      velocityY = -6.0;
  }

  function Loop() {
    Update();
    Render();
    window.setTimeout(Loop, 30);
  }

  function Update() {
    velocityY += gravity;
    positionY += velocityY;
    positionX += velocityX;

    // Collision Detection //
    if ((positionX > (239 - positionX) && positionX < (292 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (439 - positionX) && positionX < (492 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (639 - positionX) && positionX < (692 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (839 - positionX) && positionX < (892 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (839 - positionX) && positionX < (892 - positionX) && positionY > 50 && positionY < 100)) {
      positionY = 175;
      positionX = 50;
      deaths++;
      points = 0;

// circle 1

      circlex1 = 350;
      circley1 = 100;
      point1x1 = 339;
      point1x2 = 372;
      point1y1 = 110;
      point1y2 = 150;

//circle 2

      circlex2 = 575;
      circley2 = 100;
      point2x1 = 565;
      point2x2 = 595;
      point2y1 = 90;
      point2y2 = 150;

//circle 3

      point3x1 = 855;
      point3x2 = 880;
      point3y1 = 20;
      point3y2 = 50;
      circlex3 = 865;
      circley3 = 35;

    }

    if (positionY > 175.0) {
      positionY = 175.0;
      velocityY = 0.0;
      onGround = true;
    }

// End World
    if (positionX < 10 || positionX > 2000)
      velocityX *= -1;

// Point 1
    if (positionX > (point1x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point1x2 - positionX) && positionY > point1y1 && positionY < point1y2) {
      points++;
      circlex1 = -10;
      circley1 = -10;
      point1x1 = -10;
      point1x2 = -10;
      point1y1 = -10;
      point1y2 = -10;

    }


// Point 2
    if (positionX > (point2x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point2x2 - positionX) && positionY > point2y1 && positionY < point2y2) {
      points++;
      circlex2 = -10;
      circley2 = -10;
      point2x1 = -10;
      point2x2 = -10;
      point2y1 = -10;
      point2y2 = -10;
    }

// Point 3
    if (positionX > (point3x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point3x2 - positionX) && positionY > point3y1 && positionY < point3y2) {
      points++;
      circlex3 = -10;
      circley3 = -10;
      point3x1 = -10;
      point3x2 = -10;
      point3y1 = -10;
      point3y2 = -10;
    }

  }


  function drawSquare1() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(250 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle1() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex1 - positionX, circley1, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle2() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex2 - positionX, circley2, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle3() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex3 - positionX, circley3, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }


  function drawSquare2() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(450 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare3() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(650 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare5() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare4() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850 - positionX, 50, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  function drawCamera() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 2000);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 2000);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 0);
    ctx.rect(10, 5, 500, 400);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawDeaths() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Deaths: " + deaths, 10, 20);
  }

  function drawPoints() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Points: " + points, 10, 50);
  }

  function Render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    drawCircle1();
    drawCircle2();
    drawCircle3();
    drawSquare1();
    drawSquare2();
    drawSquare3();
    drawSquare4();
    drawSquare5();
    drawDeaths();
    drawPoints();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 175);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 175);
    ctx.stroke();

    drawCamera();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(positionX - 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + 10, positionY);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX - 10, positionY);
    
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly! Since I've just starting learning how to code, it took me a little while to understand the logic, but nonetheless thanks!

Comment: I had a quick question. What exactly are the following lines of code doing? I see that they are making lines in the specified coordinates, but purpose are they serving? The "camera" isn't there when the code is removed, but how are those lines making the "camera?"
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 2000);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 2000);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 0);

Comment: I have used it to fill canvas outside rectangle(gray-overlay). Since your canvas dimensions are 2000x2000 I have used these 4 lines to draw the boundary and clip the inner rectangle (visible portion) using this line of code _ctx.rect(10, 5, 500, 400)_

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Hey sorry for asking this so late, but I am having trouble getting the "camera" to synchronize with the movement of the main moving sprite. The issue is that the main moving sprite eventually runs off the screen and doesn't keep up with the camera that moves in the opposite direction. I tried solving this problem by making the main moving sprite stay in a stationary position but have the camera continue to move. The problem with keeping the moving sprite stationary is that it prevents the sprite from making the long jumps necessary to progress through the game. Do you have any ideas?